# Difference between たっぷり and たくさん?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, usage

I understand that たっぷり and たくさん means "a lot" but how can you tell apart the right time to use one or another.

Please point me a couple of examples.

Thanks

まいど ありがと

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- たくさん works both as an adverb and a no-adjective. たっぷり is an adverb.

  > - たくさんの水: OK
  > - たっぷりの水: NG (たっぷり is not a no-adj)
- たっぷり sounds a little more colloquial.
- たっぷり mainly refers to the amount of uncountable things such as liquid, cream, time, etc. たくさん can modify both countable and uncountable things.

  > - 時間をたくさん使う: OK
  > - 時間をたっぷり使う: OK
  > - 本をたくさん読む: OK (sounds like you read *many* books)
  > - 本をたっぷり読む: OK (sounds like you are reading for a long time, the number of books is not imortant)
  > - 人がたくさんいる: OK
  > - 人がたっぷりいる: NG (人 is countable)